# How to call ApplicationRecord in ApplicationMailer on RAILS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

good day!

I have an application mailer and I want to call the application record to put it on the mailer. Is it possible to do this?

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def verification_email
    @user = params[:user]
    @token = @user.verification_token

    email_template = EmailTemplate.where(category_id: 1)
    @subject = email_template.subject
    @greetings = email_template.greetings
    @content = email_template.content
    @closing = email_template.closing

    mail(to: @user.email, subject: @subject)
  end
end
```

EmailTemplate is the Application record that I want to call.

Comment: Oh sorry, I was using the where method. It should be find_by. It's okay now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work but you should get a specific template, right now you are getting an ActiveRecord::Relation

change `EmailTemplate.where(category_id: 1)`

to

`EmailTemplate.where(category_id: 1).first` or `EmailTemplate.find_by(category_id: 1)`